# Ho do i change the checked value of android.widget.CheckedTextView

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to write some test code using Appium and I have come across a scenario where I cannot set the checked value of an android.widget.CheckedTextView object. Please refer to the image below. I want to select Alpha Option 1 programmatically. I have tried the following code snippet, but as expected this will not work.

```
 @When("I select Alpha option {int}")
    public void i_select_Alpha_option(Integer int1) {


        // This coding needs to be completed
        // This is not the right way to select or change the value of a checkedTextView
        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.CheckedTextView[@text='Alpha Option 01']").click();

    }
```

Since the object type (CheckedTextView), is not clickable, the code will not work.

The question is, how do i use findElementByXpath or any other method to change the currently selected

**"Charlie Option 03"** to **Alpha Option 01** or to **Beta Option 02** as for that matter

Just point me in the right direction.

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: hi, what do you mean about  CheckedTextView is not clickable. U are currently cannot click on that by code or manually it not clickable??

Comment: by using click as in the snippet above, I am not able to change the default value of the radio buttons to Alpha Option 01

Comment: Are u sure that locator(XPath) is accurate and unique? 

- Try to print its value to make sure that the element u want

- try change to text()

- try driver.findElement(By.xpath(""))

Comment: Yes, the locator (Xpath) in this case, is accurate & unique. What do you mean by change to text()?

Comment: hmm @text->text(), just the syntax on web. I still thinking about locator accuracy. I'm using Appium inspector, not a lot exp with UI Automator Viewer, so I'm not sure. So if it really not clickable. let try get the coordinate and click by coordinate of x and y.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(@text, 'Alpha Option 01')]").click();
```

Or:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(text(), 'Alpha Option 01')]").click();
```